# HeadlessException Java

Tags: java, macos, ssh

Please forgive me if this has already been answered - I looked but couldn't find anything...

I am having trouble running a java program using SSH. I have no problems running the code from terminal locally on my Mac, but when I try and SSH into a different user on my Mac I get a HeadlessException. There aren't even any problems when I sign in as that user, and run it in their terminal window - the issue only occurs when using SSH.

I issue the following command:

```
>> ssh -X remoteguest@host
>> java LifeCounter
```

And I get the following error:

```
java.awt.HeadlessException
at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:204)
at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:536)
at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:233)
at setupGUI.<init>(LifeCounter.java:156)
at LifeCounter$1.run(LifeCounter.java:18)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

TIA

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are trying to achive?

Comment: You're quite obviously running an application with graphical UI (awt). But when you use ssh, it's just a command line interface and graphical user interface  just not part of it.

To be fair, on Mac (and most other Unixes), it's technically possible to run a graphical UI program on someone else's UI session, but it's pretty complicated.

Comment: Yes, sorry - I should have been more specific. I am trying to run a graphical application (written with Swing) by running it remotely having used SSH to connect to a machine. If I run the program locally on the server it runs without a problem, and if I run the program locally on the client it runs without a problem. The issue arrises when I try and forward the graphics using XQuartz

Comment: I haven had much experience with XQuartz per se, but given it's X Windows. I'd suggest to try setting  DISPLAY environment variable. E.g. try to ssh to the machine and then enter command as follows:
DISPLAY=:0.0 java LifeCounter

Comment: You can also check this post on running an app in someone else's session 
http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/100829/how-to-launch-a-gui-application-in-another-users-graphical-session

Comment: But beware that in both cases, you will need someone else's session available and UI will be visible in their session, not in your ssh session. If you want to see what the program is doing and interact with it, then you should use vnc or similar (Mac screen sharing seems based on vnc, so could be an option).

Comment: So is the general consensus is that what I'm trying to do isn't possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure what exactly you're trying to do. So, I'll try to cover all bases.

If you want to run graphical UI application over ssh, it's simply not possible. Graphical UI is simply not part of the protocol. When you run a program in a terminal window, your terminal windows runs in graphical UI session, so GUI is then available to your program too. But when you run it over ssh on a remote machine, then it's just a text terminal with no GUI whatsoever.

If you want to run a graphical UI, you can either use a remoting protocol which provides UI (such as vnc, screen sharing, TeamViewer, Chrome Remote Desktop etc) or you can use another user graphical session (local to that machine) to run it on his/her screen.

Now, vnc or screen sharing are easy to setup.

Using another user's session is more complicated. See the [this link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/100829/how-to-launch-a-gui-application-in-another-users-graphical-session) in a comment to the question. Note that it it is also dependent on the version of OS X on the target system and your mileage might vary. Also note, that you won't see it running - that other user will see it and interact with it.

One more option is to run X11 Server (graphical UI) on your machine and make your app, running on a remote machine, connect back to your X11 Server. But that's even more complicated. To start with, you'll need to tell your app to connect back to your machine and that connectivity (e.g. ports forwarding) must be configured first. To make it worse, OS X UI is not exactly X11 (which is why some apps need XQuartz), so you will likely have to overcome few incompatibilities here too. Again, it's not impossible, but pretty complicated and I'm afraid you're on your own here.